# Chrome not reflecting css on my pc but other chromes are working correctly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web, stylesheet

I am currently working on styling of ui on a site and am doing the development on my desktop. Currently a problem came about where the chrome on my desktop is not reflecting my updated css correctly, but it does display my updated css correctly on chrome of other devices.

I did some research and some said to use CTR + F5 and it will reload the updated css but it is not working.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Or even what may be causing the issue?

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,
Baraa

Comment: This might help, https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en.

Comment: @AmitG I should have probably mentioned that this was the first thing I tried...it didn't work...I am really curious as to why that wouldn't work? Deleting the cache should make it reload the new css...apparently in my situation that doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of the source code perhaps? I've had that happen before. If possible, try and change the name of the specific CSS file and its reference to see if it updates?

Comment: @AmitG Ok so at first I tried renaming the file and its reference and that did not work...BUT I created a whole new css file and copied the contents into it and named it differently and then of coursed referenced it and deleted the old css file and it worked!...Meh well thanks for the information, it helped and was part of the solution...if you answer the question with the solution I will accept it as an answer!

Comment: Ha, done. I know the feel though, I'm glad I helped, in whatever way I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if anyone ever has issues with their CSS files not being displayed as intended, follow the following checklist,

- Clear your cache, in the OP's case, http://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en.
- Check your development/deployment URL and make sure you're looking at the right piece o' code.
- Get firebug and check the file in the DOM viewer, https://getfirebug.com/.
- Get away from your desk and grab a breather, you'll be surprised how many questions solve themselves shortly after!